# Multiplying one value in a matrix with a range of numbers (for loop) in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, replace

I am trying to write a simple code to replace one specific value in a matrix by a range of numbers. To be clearer, assuming I have my matrix G, which is a  3x3 matrix, I want to replace the (3,3) value in G with (3,3)+i where i is 1 - 10. I want to create essentially 10 new matrices where (3,3) is replaced by (3,3)+1 and then (3,3)+2 and then (3,3)+3 up to a value of 10. 
The original matrix is:

> ```
> G=[2 4 5; 6 7 8; 8 8 2]
> ```

So, the output should a series of 10 new G matrices, so (3,3)+1 should give me

> ```
> G=[2 4 5; 6 7 8; 8 8 3]
> ```

and for (3,3)+2 it should give me:

> `G=[2 4 5; 6 7 8; 8 8 4]`

I know I can recode each matrix line by line but I want to create a loop to do this efficiently and to possibly change i to .001 increments rather than steps of 1.

I tried to do a simple code but I know I am missing the output part and I am having some bracket issues.

```
for i = 1:10;
    B[3,3]= B[3,3]+i;
end
```

Comment: Try something like `bsxfun(@plus,G,cat(3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))`.

Comment: Sorry about the above comment, what I meant to say was: `M = zeros(3,3,10);M(3,3,:) = 1:10;B = bsxfun(@plus,G,M)`. Then you can access the `i`th matrix as `B(:,:,i)`.

Comment: @Sophia14 In your code, you need to replace `B[3,3] = B[3,3]+i;` by `B(3,3) = B(3,3)+i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple:

1) Make a cell array: `B = cell(1,10);`

2) Make a matrix with 1 on position (3,3) and zeros elsewhere: `M33 = zeros(3,3); M33(3,3) = 1;`

3) Loop through the numbers from 1 to 10 and save `G+i*M33` to the `i`th entry of `B`:

```
for i = 1:10
  B{i} = G+i*M33;
end
```

You can now access the `i`th matrix as `B{i}`.

Comment: So, okay you just created another matrix and added them in the loop? I think I get it. Thanks.

Comment: How can I get the loop to automatically produce all new matrices in a new separate variable. I see I can access it by B{i} but I'd like to have each be produced and save in a new variable. So, I get if I say B{4} : G=[2 4 5; 6 7 8; 8 8 6]; but if I just say B{i} it gives me the B for the 10th i.

Comment: You can do that, but it is not something I would recommend doing! I know it is annoying to ask the question "How do I do X?" and get the answer "You shouldn't do X!". So let me turn it around! Give me one good(!) reason why you would want them in separate variables; then I'll explain you how - or more likely I'll explain why that is not a good idea and how you should do it instead!

Comment: Well, I want to use the new matrices created to then use it to show how the MLE is maximized at my original maxtrix and when I add and subtract e.g. 10 then the 'best' is the original matrix. Hope this makes sense. So, I think for the code to work after I need to be able to have all matrices available, because if I write B{i} then it only gives me the 10th and not all.

Comment: Don't worry! You can access all the matrices. `B{1}` for the first matrix, `B{2}` for the second, and so on the reason why you get the 10th matrix when you put in `B{i}` is that `i=10` so `B{i}` is the same as `B{10}` in this case!